# Recording issue through the Jmeter tool

Tags: performance, jmeter

When I am recording the same .net scenario through the badboy or Blazemeter tool, it recorded the successfully without any exception but Jmeter throws exception to record this particular scenario. So, I have used the badboy tool request in my Jmeter script and replace that request through the badboy request but there i am able to see the below Fig1 in the badboy request Parameter sent parameter pattern are different to Jmeter request as displays on Fig2.

I have also tried to fixed to

- Compare the parameter
- Change the Content Type Deposition as well as experiment with HTTP headers 
  request

At the same place when i used the  Blazemeter request in my Jmeter scenario that time i am unable to "export successfully .jmx file" .

badboy tool HTTP Request(exported into the Jmeter)on figure1

[image]

[image]

Comment: what are the issues you were facing with jmeter recorder ?

Comment: when i am recording through the Jmeter tool it throws exception  in the response code

Comment: Please give more details about the exception.

Comment: When i am click on particular Button (Sign&Close), It throws excetion like" <MessageValidationErrors><Error><Value>Unexpected Error occurred, please report to the Helpdesk</Value></Error></MessageValidationErrors>"

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add Apache JMeter generated certificate Authority to your browser as per this doc:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder

> Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording

Then ensure you read this:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html